# How to solve this question on time and work?

Tags: arithmetic

Question:

"Pipe A can fill the tank in 4 hours, while pipe B can fill it in 6 hours working separately. Pipe C can empty the whole tank in 4 hours. Ramesh opened the pipe A and B simultaneously to fill the empty tank. He wanted to adjust his alarm so that he could open the pipe C when it was half-filled, but he mistakenly adjusted his alarm at a time when his tank would be 3/4th filled. What is the time difference between both the cases, to fill the tank fully."

Doubt:

I am unable to approach the problem properly. A detailed justification into how the problem should be approach will do a lot of benifit.

Comment: $C$'s rate of emptying the tank matches $A$'s rate of filling the tank so when $C$ is opened the tank will fill at $B$'s rate of $\frac{1}{6}$ of a tank per hour. Now just use that number to compare the time it takes to fill a half tank and a quarter of a tank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret it correctly, it's asking for the time difference between filling the tank from 1/2 full and filling the tank from 3/4 full.

Regardless of whatever happened beforehand, the rate of flow into the tank in both of these cases is the same, as all pipes are always opened. So all you must do is simply determine that final rate of flow, and see how long it takes to fill the remaining tank in either case.